# JLabel ignoring setBounds Method

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

```
public class Window extends JFrame {

public Window() {
    super("Whatever Window idk");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(300, 300);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
    label1.setText("label1");
    label1.setBounds(40, 20, 100, 30);

    JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
    label2.setText("label2");
    label2.setBounds(40, 20, 100, 30);

    JLabel label3 = new JLabel();
    label3.setText("label3");
    label3.setBounds(40, 20, 100, 30);

    add(label1);
    add(label2);
    add(label3);
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    new Window();
}
```

I constructed `label1` with given bounds. These bounds should put my label in the upper left corner to center of the window.

That was not the case as the label was placed in the center left bound of the window.

Then, after changing the bounds did not work, I created `label2` with the same bounds, to check if the lines would "merge" or something. Turns out, adding label 2 pushes label 1 into the correct location (as defined in `setBounds()`) and places label 2 in its stead on the leftmost center position.
Now, adding label 3 with the exact same bounds does the same thing with label 2. So label 1 and 2 merge in the defined bounds while label 3 is placed left-center.

My question: Why?

Done in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: 1. Do not set bounds manually. The is what [layout mangers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) are for. (Side note: the bounds you set to all 3 labels are the same)  2. You are adding the labels to a `JFrame` which by default uses `BorderLayout`.  This `add(label1);` adds `label1` to BorederLayout CENTER position which can accept only one component, not 3.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options

1)set the frames content pane to an panel having null layout

```
 setContentPane(new JPanel(null));
```

2)set the existing content pane layout to null

```
 getContentPane().setLayout(null);
```

add either of these 2 lines after u have called the super() method